# Laravel. Group query by parameter and max date

Tags: laravel, дата, запрос, max

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сгруппировать записи по **ItemId** и выбрать запись с максимальной датой. На фото начальная таблица и результат.

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_ItemCounters t1
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ItemID, MAX(Date) AS Date
    FROM tbl_ItemCounters GROUP BY ItemID
) AS max USING (ItemID, Date)
```

Такая конструкция работает, как я могу переписать её, используя **Laravel Eloquent query builder**?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
TblItemCounter::select('*')
    ->selectRaw('MAX(Date) as Date')
    ->groupBy('ItemId')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Так она верно выбирает максимальную дату, но Id берёт первой записи, а не той, у которой максимальная дата